# CSS wrong behaviour

Tags: android, css, cordova, webview, crosswalk

**EDIT :**

Seems like it's a bug from crosswalk when using `box-shadow` and `border-radius` at the same time. No fix found for now...

On the `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`, CSS isn't displaying as it was in other webviews.

Here are working examples on browser's and Android default webview:

[image: Working select]

[image: Working menu]

And here the same elements on `Crosswalk plugin`'s webview on Android:

[image: Not working select]
[image: Not working menu]

Relevant CSS:

**1. Selection :**

```
.cat-circler {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 340px;
  width: 340px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 5px #111111; }

.rounded-image-parent {
  z-index: 5; }

.rounded-image-parent .rounded-image {
  border: 5px solid #444444;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 130px; }
```

**2. Menu's background saucer**

```
.menuSaucer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  background-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #555555;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #555555;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #555555; }


.menuSaucer.menuSauceropen {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition: 0.3s opacity linear;
  z-index: 10; }

.menuSauceropen {
  opacity: 1; }
```

Did I miss something? Why is it displaying that way?